# Giving the script tag an ID

Tags: html, standards, scripting

I came across a scenario where giving a `script` element an `id` attribute would solve a problem easily. However, after reading about the `script` element at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_script.asp) and [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html), it seems doing so could have some unforeseen consequences.

Has anyone come across any of these issues with browsers such as Chrome, Safari, FF3 up and IE 7 up?

Comment: This is an old question, but it looks like Google Tag Manager strips out the 'id' attribute, so it's probably worth investing in a fallback approach (perhaps).

Answer (score 111, accepted):

It's fine in all current browsers.

The only browser that got `<script id>` wrong was Netscape 4, which we stopped caring about a long, long time ago.

That quirksmode page seems to be badly out of date, what with its use of `language` attributes, script `<!--` hiding, and `application/x-javascript`. Its advice about avoiding `<script>` in the `<body>` (and putting it in `<head>` instead) is at odds with today's encouraged practices.

If we're talking `<script>` attribute compatibility problems: `defer` doesn't work everywhere so don't rely on it; `charset` doesn't work everywhere, and neither does the charset parameter on the served script's Content-Type, so your script charset had better match the page; `type` should always be `text/javascript` and not one of the non-working alternatives the pedants who wrote RFC 4329 would like you to use.

Answer (score 23):

Keep in mind that setting the `id` on any element introduces a new global variable with the same name as the `id` attribute:

[image: id as a global variable]

Comment: This is an incredibly important point! I recently added IDs automatically via a CMS and had to change it to `data-id` because it was overwriting global variables.

Comment: One way to avoid overwriting global variables would be to name IDs with dashes (`-`) included since variables cannot contain dashes but IDs can.

Answer (score 8):

If you're still having to support Netscape 4, you've got a lot of trouble – and the pity and condolences of the rest of the developer world.

Short answer, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 6):

I know a long time has passed, but I thought it would be nice to point that when you look at [W3 Schools definition of the script tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_script.asp), you see at some point that

> The  tag also supports the [Global Attributes in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_standardattributes.asp).

and amongst those attributes, ta-da, you will find your lovely id.

The same goes for a whole lot of tags, which will certainly give us a lot of flexibility when pulling those nice trick from the hat.

Comment: Never refer w3schools as a standard reference please

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a browser would have a problem by adding an `id` attribute to a `script` element.

On some of my sites, that load additional JavaScripts via JavaScript, I have added a `class` attribute to make referencing them easier. The validator did not complain.