# Replace single quote AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'd like to use the `.replace("'", r"\'")` method to avoid problems caused by single quotes within JSON strings.. and so that my factory works ...as intended

Simplest solution I could find from [This  post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012721/json-parse-single-quote-inside-name) suggests the `replace` method, however, beeing new in JS, I have troubles implementing it  within my factory.

I am not quite sure where and how to put it, so that any given controller  calling different function  (especially the `getDishes` and `getDish`functions at the end of the script below) all get a "formatted string"

### Factory :

```
angular.module('wmapp.factory_dishes', [])

.factory('dishesFactory', function (){
var factory = {
    dishes :[
        {   nameEnglish: 'beef burgungdy', 
            nameLocal: 'boeuf bourgignon',
            description: 'xxxxxx',
            region: 'sicile',
            itemid: 'IT018',
            cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'IT',
            country:'France',
            dishCategory: 'Meat',

        },
        {   nameEnglish: 'duck liver', 
            nameLocal: 'foie gras',
            description: 'xxxxxx',
            region: 'sicile',
            itemid: 'IT021',
            cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'IT',
            country:'France',
            dishCategory: 'fruit',

        },  
        {   nameEnglish: 'veal stew',
            nameLocal: 'blanquette de veau',
            description: 'xxxxxx',  
            region: 'parme',
            itemid: 'IT023',
            cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'IT',
            country:'France',
            dishCategory: 'fruit',

        },
        {   nameEnglish: 'onion soup', 
            nameLocal: 'soxxxxxx',
            region: 'vanitia',
            itemid: 'IT022',
            cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'IT',
            imageSource: '( "img/" + dish.cuisineTypeIsoCode + "/" + dish.itemid + "small.jpg")',
            country:'France',
            dishCategory: 'Soup',
        },

        {  nameEnglish: 'TAPENADE',
           nameLocal: 'Tapenade', 
           description: 'xxxxxx',
           region: 'Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur', 
           regioncode: 'FR.B8', 
           itemid: 'FR002', 
           cuisineTypeIsoCode: 'FR', 
           dishCategory: 'Entrée / Appetizers', 
           country: 'France'}




      ], 
      getDishes : function (){
        return factory.dishes;
      },
      getDish :function (itemid){
        var dish = {};
        angular.forEach(factory.dishes, function(value, key) {
            if (value.itemid == itemid){
                dish = value
            }
        });       

        return dish;
      }
}
return factory;
```

})

Comment: Have you got those `dishes ` hardcoded inside your factory? If yes the problem is that your js is syntactically invalid.

Comment: yes for the moment they are hard coded, will set webservices later. I get the json string from an Excel file combining value from a various cell in a single  JSON string. I can amend the syntax components , but not the cell content

Comment: Well, the question has nothing to do with js or angular. Your code is invalid  right now. Escape those quotes manually.

Comment: there must be a solution to  "scan"  through an  array and replace caracters .. (what is the replace method for then)  I can't  escape those quotes manually  way too many entries

Comment: You wont get an array since the syntax is *invalid*. Your js file generate parse error. Means no execution phase. Period. 
As you can see SO failed to highlight your code sample.

Comment: And btw why are you calling it JSON? It's not. It is javascript. Invalid javascript.

Comment: nevermind thanks for your time, i'll search somewhere else