# Convert String to nested array of characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string passed to me like

```
var str = "['♫', ['►', 'Play']]";
```

Multiple entries can be there

Need to **convert it to Array**.

How can It be done?

**PS: No eval() please.** and also no Jquery

**Note:** I have tried JSON.parse, but it didn't work for me. It gives following error:

> Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: Please explain more. Also SO is not get code for free site, so please share your effort

Comment: `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: try using str.split(",")?

Comment: @Rajesh he can't share his effort, since he doesn't know where to start.

Comment: @Rajesh What more info do you need? Could you please explain. I guess Question is self explanatory and I tried JSON.parse() and multiple other things which didn't work..

Comment: Replace the single quotes with double quotes, then use `JSON.parse`. More basically, fix your server to return proper JSON (with double-quoted strings).

Comment: @GSerg It gives Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: @torazaburo as mentioned by OP, he has tried `JSON,parse` but it didn't work. If he would have mentioned such cases, he would have not received these downvotes.

Comment: @Geeky can't use split as it will split the internal arrays also..

Comment: Downvoters, atleast please give comments also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

In other words, fix the quotes so that it is valid JSON, then you will be able to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: A useful reference: [JSON parse - single quote inside name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012721/json-parse-single-quote-inside-name)