# How can I load and unload(remove) css and javascript imports/files on will?

Tags: javascript

Upon a certain user interaction (a button click) I try to dynamically load a CSS file and a script file in my webpage and it worked fine. The CSS files bring in a few styles which get applied to the webpage. In the Javascript file, I have put some code inside a *setInterval()* which gets executed from an IIFY so that the code can run infinitely at a 1-second interval.

But when I tried to unload(remove) them, the CSS file gets removed easily but the script file is creating a problem. By removing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/demo.css">` from the index.html file, the styles brought in by it gets removed from index.html also. By removing the `<script src="res/demo.js"></script>` the underlying code keeps on running.

Sample code in the GIT repo:

https://github.com/anirbannath/loading-unloading-css-js.git

How can I stop the scripts and flush out the memory it takes other than refreshing the page entirely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove appended script javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390445/remove-appended-script-javascript)

Comment: The script tag can be removed from DOM but the underlying script still works. Can there be a solution to stop and flush out the underlying script?

Comment: You can disable a stylesheet by setting [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) property. I'm not aware of actual unloading of either of these. There's [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390445/remove-appended-script-javascript/9471916#9471916) of mine about scripts, but that's more experimental and hackish ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an anonymous interval then you can loop through all the intervals and stop them **without touching the script that you're importing** (So it works for 3rd party scripts):

```js
//Your imported script file
(function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Hello again!')
  }, 1000)
})()

//Your main script file
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (var i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
      window.clearInterval(i);
  }
  //remove script
})
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn">STOP IT!</a>
```

> ## **OR**

If you have DO have control over the imported script, then you can:

1. Give the IIFE a name to be able to reassign it later
2. Create a variable outside of the IIFE
3. Assign the interval to that variable inside the IIFE
4. When you click the button then first **clear the interval** and then **reassign the variables** to something else (making it eligible for garbage collection) and finally remove the script tag.

```js
//Your imported script file
let interval;
(function theFunc() {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('Hello again!')
  }, 1000)
})()

//Your main script file
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = null;
  theFunc = null;
  //remove script
})
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn">STOP IT!</a>
```

Comment: this is assuming you have full control over the contents of the script and from the GitHub page I got the impression that that's not the case

Comment: You're right yes, @Joeri ,  that is assuming that. He is adding the demo.js from his own folder structure and not from a third party, so I assume it's possible.

Comment: quick variation on your answer. This would work on third party scripts as well, thought it's not as elegant. https://jsfiddle.net/6chLbq72/

Comment: Yeah, these solutions I know. As @Joeri said, I am trying to use a 3rd party library and do not have control over it. Is there a way out for that?

Comment: You could load them with an xhr and insert them like this. https://jsfiddle.net/6chLbq72/

Comment: Okay @ProgrammerForFun , I've updated the answer to be able to stop the interval even if it is from a third party script.